# ReactJS NextJS - Persisting session information with client-side routing

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I am using NextJS with ExpressJS custom server. ExpressJS set up session cookies for my NextJS app. I can get session information in getInitialProps which works well when I am using server-side routing (like normal page load) but when using client-side routing with next/link Link I cannot get session information. Please suggest how I can get session information stored in cookies when using client-side routing and cookies cannot be accessed on client-side.

Comment: Post your code.

Comment: ```static async getInitialProps({ Component, ctx }) {

    const session = getClientSession(ctx);

    let pageProps = {};

    if (Component.getInitialProps) {
      pageProps = await Component.getInitialProps(ctx);
    }

    pageProps._appSession = session;

    return {pageProps};

  }```

code from _app page where session object is created when server side routing is done.

Comment: What I mean is, edit your question and include your code. Don't post it as a comment. The idea behind Stack Overflow is to not only get your question answered, but also to provide a resource for other people to find answers to their own questions. If you provide a clear question with code examples, it makes it more likely that your question will be useful to people other than you. Also, it makes it easier for people to answer your question now.

Answer (score 0):

You should use ReactJS context which can allow you to pass props from _app page to all components which need session information.